# I am getting error in flutter exception error

Tags: flutter

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This _ModalScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
_ModalScope-[LabeledGlobalKey<_ModalScopeState>#96ae3]
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
HaveAccountOrNot)

The code is:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_app/screens/signup.dart';
import 'package:food_app/screens/widget/haveaaccountornot.dart';
import 'package:food_app/screens/widget/mybutton.dart';
import 'package:food_app/screens/widget/mypasswordtextformfield.dart';
import 'package:food_app/screens/widget/mytextformfield.dart';
import 'package:food_app/screens/widget/toptitle.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffold = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  static String p =
      r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
  static RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);

  void vaildation() {
    if (email.text.isEmpty && password.text.isEmpty) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Both field are required"),
        ),
      );
    } else if (email.text.isEmpty) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Email is required"),
        ),
      );
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(email.text)) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Email Is Not Vaild"),
        ),
      );
    } else if (password.text.isEmpty) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("password is required"),
        ),
      );
    } else if (password.text.length < 8) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("password is too small"),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  final TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      key: scaffold,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TopTitle(subsTitle: "Welcome To FoodZone", title: "Login"),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      MyTextFormField(
                        title: "Email",
                        controller: email,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      MyPasswordTextFormField(
                        title: "Password",
                        controller: password,
                      ),
                      MyButton(
                        name: "Login",
                        onPressed: () {
                          vaildation();
                        },
                      ),
                      HaveAccountOrNot(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (ctx) => SignUp(),
                            ));
                          },
                          title: "I don't have an Account",
                          subsTitle: "SignUp"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When did the exception occur? Just after entering the `Login` page?

Comment: When I run the main.dart file that time. Basically when I try to run my android project this error occurs and there shows white screen on the emulator.

Comment: If that's the case, we'll need the code related to the initial page. Most importantly, it's necessary to check when and where attempts to change the page's state are made, as the error can occur if the state is modified before the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build` error usually caused by some function called at initState. you can try add `addPostFrameCallback` to your initState code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // your code
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Your provided sample code seems just fine, for more context you can share the entire file code here so we can figure out what is the main issue.